# proof or disprove :If p is a prime number of 5 or more, there is no integer n satisfying $p + 1 = n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

proof or disprove :If p is a prime number of 5 or more, there is no integer n satisfying $p + 1 = n^2$

first attempt:
suppose $p>5$ and $p$ is prime and prove that there is no n integer that satisfy $p+1=n^2$. let $ p=7$, $n= \sqrt {p+1}$ , $n= \sqrt 8$ and is not integer

i think this proof is wrong? because i only proved for p=7

second attempt:
let $p=n^2-1 $,$ p=(n+1 )(n-1)$, since $p$ is prime and bigger than 5 by assumption , $n-1=1$, $n=2$, $p=3.2$ , this contradict the fact that p is prime and bigger than 5, hence there is no integer n that satisfy $p + 1 = n^2$
is this looks fine?

now im trying to proof by contrapositive,
there is n integer satisfy $ p+1=n^2$ and trying to proof p is prime and p<5

$n=\sqrt {p+1}$ , suppose $p=3$ ,$ n= \sqrt 4$, $n=2$
so there is n integer  satisfy $p+1=n^2$, hence If p is a prime number of 5 or more, there is no integer n satisfying $p + 1 = n^2$

please give review thanks! if im not sure that the proposition is correct, how can i proof by contradiction ?

Comment: This is completely equivalent to the question you just asked.  The proof you gave there is correct.

Comment: @saulspatz thankyou but for this questions , is the only way to proof is by contradiction?  how can i prove the " there is no integer n satisfying $p+1=n^2$" ?

Comment: The same way.  Factor $n^{2n}-1$